# Extract string by position

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a row with countries separated by `;`. This is an example located in a cell: `RO;BE;AU;CN;DE;UK;ES;HU;NL;SE;AT;EL;CZ`.

On the other hand, I have another cell with organizations, also separated with `;`: e.g `Org1; Org2; Org3...` and it has the same position as the countries.

Now, I have to find the position of a country (e.g. `DE`) and extract the organization in the same position in the other cell.

What I have identified is the position by using `FIND` formula. Now I need to extract the organization separated by commas but I do not know how to do it. I've tried `LEFT`, `RIGHT` function... Also `INDIRECT`.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have option then split the data in multi-cell format and then use a function like `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` & `MATCH`.

Comment: Please post your efforts to date.

Comment: With first list in `A1` and 2nd in `A2`, try something like: `=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FIND("DE",A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("DE",A1)),";","")))`. If you don't have access to `FILTERXML` then you can find another usefull option to extract the nth word [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the fun of it.

It can be done with the basic excel formula's as long as your really never want to look at the formula again and don't care about the performance.

[image: How it looks in Excel]

And here are all the used formula's

```
=FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";")
=LEFT(B2;C6)
=LEN(C7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C7;";";""))
=SUBSTITUTE(B3;";";"|";C8)
=FIND("|";C9)
=FIND(";";B3&";";C10+1)
=MID(C9;C10+1;C11-C10-1)

=MID(B3;FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(B3;";";"|";LEN(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";"));";";""))))+1;FIND(";";B3&";";FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(B3;";";"|";LEN(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";"));";";""))))+1)-FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(B3;";";"|";LEN(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2; FIND(";" & B4 &";";";" & B2 & ";"));";";""))))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with macro written in VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractOrganization()
    Dim i As Long, countries As Variant, organizations As Variant, country As String
    ' take lists from cells and split them by ;
    countries = Split(Cells(1, 1), ";")
    organizations = Split(Cells(2, 1), ";")
    country = "BE"
    For i = LBound(countries) To UBound(countries)
        If countries(i) = country Then Exit For
    Next

    MsgBox organizations(i)
End Sub
```

And here's my sheet setup:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Michal!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013 or higher then you can use FILTERXML approach as shown by @JvdV. For all versions you can use:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(";"&B2,";",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:$A$10)*99,99))=B4),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(";"&B3,";",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:$A$10)*99,99)))`

Where

Cell B2 holds RO;BE;AU;CN;DE;UK;ES;HU;NL;SE;AT;EL;CZ
Cell B3 holds Org1; Org2; Org3..
Cell B4 holds the key you are looking for e.g. RO.

It is assumed that all entries in the source list are unique and there are 10 entries to be split. If you have more then you need to change `ROW($A$1:$A$10)` to maximum entries to suit your case like `ROW($A$1:$A$99)` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much shrivallabha.redij!!

Answer (score 1):

Because you've tagged the question with VBA, you can use an UDF to get the value.

This UDF got three arguments:

1. Cell of countries
2. Cell of orgs
3. Country you are looking for

   ```
   Function GET_ORG(ByVal vCountries As Range, ByVal vOrgs As Range, ByVal vThisCountry As String) As String
   Dim Countries As Variant
   Countries = Split(vCountries.Value, ";")

   Dim Orgs As Variant
   Orgs = Split(vOrgs.Value, ";")

   Dim i As Byte

   For i = LBound(Countries) To UBound(Countries) Step 1
       If Countries(i) = vThisCountry Then Exit For
   Next i

   GET_ORG = Orgs(i)

   Erase Countries
   Erase Orgs

   End Function
   ```

The test I made:

[image]

In cell `D2` my formula is `=GET_ORG(A1;A2;D1)`

Comment: @Peh  I can't format the code part as I've been doing in the last years. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Using **SPLIT, MATCH AND INDEX** excel formulas you can get it

```
FORMULA

=INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ";"), MATCH(B3, SPLIT(B1, ";")))
```

**EXAMPLE:**

Apply above formula at B4 cell

```
    A               B

1   COUNTRIES       A;B;C;D;E
2   ORG             Org1;Org2;Org3;Org4;Org5
3   Search CODE     B
4   Result          Org2 (=INDEX(SPLIT(B2, ";"), MATCH(B3, SPLIT(B1, ";"))))
```

Comment: have you tested `SPLIT` function? I tested formula and it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, I tested and works fine, screenshot for your reference https://ibb.co/mb5Z4RT

Comment: It doesn't work in Excel. I suspect you are working with Google Sheets.

Comment: Yes, I work with google sheets, 
Can you explain what error you are getting with excel then?

Comment: Excel doesn't accept the function it highlights the word `SPLIT` and returns 
 message `That function isn't valid`.

Comment: Okay thank you, it works with Google sheets well and I use excel very less

Comment: @RameshN Please note that GoogleSheets and Excel are 2 completly different programs with different syntax. There might be similarities but in the end they are completely independent and different.